# Finding if given graph is eulerian or semi-eulerian

Tags: python, graph

I'm working on my school project and I'm struggling at the very end of my code. The last line which suppose to check if the graph is semi-eulerian isn't working and I'm out of ideas how to fix it. I'm a beginner at Python, hope to see some good advice :)

```
    graph = {
    "1" : set(["2", "6"]),
    "2" : set(["1", "6", "7", "3"]),
    "3" : set(["2","7","4", "5"]),
    "4" : set(["3", "5"]),
    "5" : set(["3","4", "7", "6"]),
    "6" : set(["1","2", "7", "5"]),
    "7" : set(["2", "3", "5"]),
}

def path(x, node, visited):
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for n in x[node]:
            path(x,n, visited)
    return visited

visited = path(graph,"1", [])

print("Graph path: ", visited)

values = list(map(len, graf.values()))
print(values)


if all(map(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, values)):
    print("Eulerian")
else list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, values)) >= 2:
    print("Semi-eulerian")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a beginner you should probably stay away from lambdas; those make scripts that much harder to read.

From a quick look at what you posted, you're comparing a list to an integer.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list

I have no idea what the output of the filter/lambda is but when you wrap it with the list function you're going to get a list. I'm surprised the script didn't outright crash considering that asking if a list is "greater than" an integer makes no programmatic or mathematical sense. Barring that, it would fall down to the list equals integer condition which will always be False.

Additionally your if/else structure is broken - you probably meant "elif" (else if).

Just a guess, but if the last condition is "Semi-eulerian if there are at least 2 odd numbers in values", then you probably meant (after the if clause):

```
elif len(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, values))) >= 2:
    print("Semi-eulerian")
```